# htaccess redirects with subdomains and https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, subdomain

I'm working with a HostGator account that is hosting two domains (both using SSL). I also have subdomains set up on both of these that don't use the SSL. I have a redirect set up so that http will redirect to https, but I'm having problems working with the subdomains.

Here is what I need it to do:

http://site1.com -> https://site1.com

http://www.site1.com -> https://site1.com

dev.site1.com -> no redirect

http://site2.com -> https://site2.com

http://www.site2.com -> https://site2.com

dev.site2.com -> no redirect

What is happening now is that when I go to dev.site2.com (whether or not I put in https) what I see is https://site1.com, although it doesn't appear to be redirecting, because the address bar still shows dev.site2.com

Here is what I have in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~hostgatorusername/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dev.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~hostgatorusername/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~hostgatorusername/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm still trying to fully grasp htaccess, so I'd love if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Update: I also need https://www.site1.com  to redirect to  https://site1.com and 
https://www.site2.com  to redirect to  https://site2.com

Comment: `!=dev.*` is not a valid regex, unless you've got an http host that literally has a `=` in its name. `=` is not an equality test in regexs, it's just a char like a or P or 3

Comment: Thanks. I'm not very good with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~hostgatorusername/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~hostgatorusername/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: This does the main redirects, but when I go to dev.site2.com I still see site1.com instead. Also, and I'm sorry I forgot include this, I need <https://www.site1.com>  to redirect to  <https://site1.com> and <https://www.site2.com>  to redirect to  <https://site2.com/>

Comment: For some reason I can't get bare urls to show up in the comments, so I put an update in the original post.

Comment: There is no way above rule can do redirect for `dev.site2.com`. 1. Try in a different browser to avoid 301 caching and 2. Check your WP permalink settings.

Comment: I tried opening it in an entirely different browser, and even on another computer. The thing is, I'm not sure if actually is redirecting, or if there is something else going on, because when I go to http://dev.site2.com the address bar shows https://dev.site2.com, but the browser is actually displaying site1.com

Comment: Do I need to have a seperate htaccess file in the site2.com folder?

Comment: If URL in browser is not changing that means rules are working fine. Your content is coming from WP which you will have to cross check.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cross check". There are two different WordPress installs, each with its own content and different themes. What's showing is the content and theme from site1.com.

Comment: i mean rules are working fine but I didn't get what you mean by `when I go to dev.site2.com the address bar shows dev.site2.com, but the browser is actually displaying site1.com`

Comment: Oh, I mean that dev.site2.com still shows in the address bar, but what the browser actually loads is site1.com. Imagine going to amazon.com and seeing the Google homepage instead, even though amazon.com is still what the address bar reads. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes I understood that part but that is not driven by rewrite rules. If you comment out both top suggested rules in my answer and just leave standard WP stuff. And then when you open `dev.site2.com` in your browser what do you see?

Comment: Turns out this was a problem caused by HostGator. They had incorrectly installed the SSL, and it was somehow screwing up the redirects. At least that's what they told me.

Comment: oh great to know it worked out. Once you're satisfied with results can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. One last thing I'm trying to straighten out is how to make sure all the www. addresses redirect to their root (like www.site1.com to site1.com). Because the ssl is not set up for the www version of each site.

Comment: Actually 2nd rule in my answer is for removing `www`. Of course WP permalink settings should also be same without `www`.